# How to use the full width when an UI element is invisible in iphone?

Tags: iphone, swift

[image]

I have a label and a button like in the above picture. I like the label to use full width when I click on hide button.

I tried setting the width to 0, how ever it does not change the label with. Is this correct? or is there a better way to do this ?

```
blockingButton.frame = CGRectMake(blockingButton.frame.origin.x, blockingButton.frame.origin.y, 0, blockingButton.frame.height)
```

Answer (score 0):

No, 0 can cause problems.
Try this:

```
blockingButton.frame = CGRectMake(blockingButton.frame.origin.x, blockingButton.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, blockingButton.frame.height)
```